# How read input and save it into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm learning programming in Python. And as my first attempt, I'm trying to make a program that needs the user to key in the user's data and then the program stores it. If possible, write it to a `.txt` file.

I started with this;

```
userKey = ["name ","age ","gender "]
userValue = [input("name "),input("age "),input("gender ")]
userData = dict(zip(userKey, userValue))
```

But it only runs once, so I tried this:

```
def userData():
    userKey = ["name ","age ","gender "]
    userValue = [input("name "),input("age "),input("gender ")]
    userData = dict(zip(userKey, userValue))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(userData)
```

But it doesn't do what my first code did. How can I make it keep going.

Comment: You are missing parenthesis, `print(userData())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other solutions will work, since you have to **return** something from your function.

```
def userData():
    userKey = ["name ","age ","gender "]
    userValue = [input("name "),input("age "),input("gender ")]
    data = dict(zip(userKey, userValue))
    return data
```

If you want to be able to add multiple users, you can do something like this, using a `while` loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ask = True
    # Get user data
    userdata = userData()
    # Write description on first row (table header)
    with open("user.txt", 'w') as f:
        for key in userdata.keys():
            f.write(key + "\t")
        f.write("\n")

    while ask:
        # Append user data to text file
        with open("user.txt", 'a') as f:
            for data in userdata.values():
                f.write(data + "\t")
            f.write("\n")
        # Ask wheter you want to add a new user and check user input
        chk = True
        while chk:
            add = input("Add another user? [y]/n ")  # y is the default answer
            if not add or add=='y' or add=='yes':
                chk = False
                userdata = userData()
            elif add=='n' or add=='no':
                ask=False
                chk = False
            else:  # Prompt again if user entered an invalid string
                print("Please enter y or n")
```

Here, I also check for valid input, something you also need to do in your `userData` function to avoid user submitting bad values (like strings for years, an invalid gender, or invalid name, e.g. containing numbers)

Comment: I'm a total beginner in programming and here in stack overflow so im a bit shocked as how fast i get answered and here's the most informative answer i get. Not only it solve my problem but it teaches me something else. Thanks David and also the others who answered as well. Community wins!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def userData():
    userKey = ["name ","age ","gender "]
    userValue = [input("name "),input("age "),input("gender ")]
    userData = dict(zip(userKey, userValue))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(userData())
```

IT SHOULD WORK NOW.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parentheses, so change this:

```
print(userData)
```

to this:

```
print(userData())
```

and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing the parentheses in your function call, so it should be something like this:

```
print(userData())
```

Then, in order to make the program keep asking user for input you should make use of a loop to do that:

```
def userData():
    while True:
        userKey = ["name ","age ","gender "]
        userValue = [input("name "),input("age "),input("gender ")]
        userData = dict(zip(userKey, userValue))
```

To stop execution, you press `Ctrl+C`.

Then, in order to write that into a file, use the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function in Python:

```
...
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'w') as my_file:
    my_file.write('data')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to do that

```
def userData():
   userKey = ["name ","age ","gender "]
   userValue = [input("name "),input("age "),input("gender ")]
   userData = dict(zip(userKey, userValue))
   return userData
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(userData())
```